# Let A be a n x n matrix with n unique positive eigenvalues. Proof there exists a matrix B such dat $B^2 = A$ and that B is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I don't know how to proof that B exists but I managed to proof that B is invertible like this:

We know A is diagonalizable because A has n unique eigenvalues. This means det(A) must be a positve number. det(B^2) = det(A) so det(B)det(B) = det(A). Because det(A) is positive, det(B) is non-zero  and thus B is invertible.

Does this proof B exists? I think it doesn't but I have no other idea to proof a matrix exists.

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof is not correct.

**Hint:** If you have a diagonal matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_2 \\ & & \lambda_3}
$$
where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are positive, then show that there exists a **diagonal** matrix $B$ that satisfies $B^2 = A$.

---

**Hint 2:** Show that if $B = PDP^{-1}$ (where $D$ is diagonal), then $B^2 = PD^2P^{-1}$.

Comment: This is the diagonal matrix B with the roots of the eigenvalues :) I think if A is symmetric you can just take the root of everything in A to get B but I don't see a solution for it if A isn't symmetric

Comment: @DucoVDS See my edit.

Comment: PDP^-1 * PDP^-1 = PDDP or PD^2P if P is orthonormal. So I need to find a orthonormal matrix P such that P * D^2 * P^-1 = A?

Comment: Why are you looking at orthonormal matrices? We only need $P$ to be invertible.

Comment: Oh oops! I thought P * P^-1 would be the identity matrix only if P was orthonormal but that isn't the case.

Comment: So the final answer would be B^2 = P * D^2 * P^-1 = A?

Comment: Right, that's what I asked you to show. Do you see how you can use this to answer the original question?

Comment: I think I remember that because we have unique eigenvalues there are 3 unique eigenvectors, we can normalize these vectors and put them in a matrix and call that matrix P, but I don't know the rule why this works.

Comment: This gets back to the definition of the word "diagonalizable". Maybe checking your notes on that will be helpful.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I can't find a definition in my book that states this, but I will look into it online, thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay so I found out it doesn't have to be orthonormal, P has to be the eigenvectors as columns in the matrix so I think I totally understand it now.